# Creating a function that performs a "`DotExpand`"

Tags: functions, function-construction

When you make a `Dot[a,(a+b+c)]` the output will be:

```
a.(a + b + c)
```

I want to make a function that expands the dot product, for the previous example would be:

```
a^2 + a.b + a.c
```

I don't have much knowledge about pure function. I start to create the function as following:

```
DotExpand[Dot[l_, r_]] := Map[Times[#, #] &, {l, r}]

In[36]:= DotExpand[(a + b + c).a]

Out[36]= {(a + b + c)^2, a^2}
```

As you see, is not working. What I have do modify to works?

Comment: see`TensorExpand`?

Comment: Ok, but if I want to create my own `TensorExpand`, some like a `DotExpand`?

Comment: Replace the first line by Apply[Times[#1, #2] &, {l, r}];

Comment: The output still the same @WenChern if I use `Dot`: `a (a + b + c)`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, are you looking for something using `Distribute`?

```
DotExpand[u_,v_]:=Distribute[Dot[u,v]]
```

For example,

```
DotExpand[a,a+b+c]
```

> a.a + a.b + a.c

```
DotExpand[a+b,b+c]
```

> a.b + a.c + b.b + b.c